# Moving a partiton

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I recently installed Xubuntu (my first time) and created two partitions: the root partition for the OS and my own partition (to store musc,movies,photos etc.), but insted of creating my partition in /home I created it in /usr. My question is: How can I move the /usr partition in /home partition ?

Comment: In a terminal, what's the output of `tail -n +7 /etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the content. Please note that the following instructions may lead to data loss if you do not do them right. Therefore for such operations it is wise to make a backup first. Also note that I assume that you do this steps in a running system. Perhaps it would be easier to do the steps with a live CD. This only works if the `/home` is not encrypted. *Also note that I write all commands from my head and have not tested it*.

First unmount the partition `/usr`:

```
sudo umount /usr
```

Next mount the partition to some arbitary mount point:

```
sudo mount <partition> /mnt
```

You have to replace `<partition` with your real partition (e.g. `/dev/sda5`). I cannot tell you which partition is used.

Next you have to copy all data to the `/usr` directory:

```
sudo cp -dpR /mnt /usr
```

After copying all data you can wipe the data from the partition:

```
sudo rm -rf /mnt/*
```

Now please check if there is any hidden file left:

```
sudo ls -a /mnt
```

This command should only show two files: `.` and `..`

Next you can copy the content of your home directory to the wiped partition:

```
sudo cp -dpR /home /mnt
```

Next you have to change the file `fstab` and change the entry `/usr` to `/home`.

Now when everything was done right you can reboot and have your home data on the extra partition.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide: [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).